# ACME and DNS configuration for Ejabberd cluster

Tags: erlang, ejabberd, ejabberd-module, acme, srv-record

I've setup an ejabberd cluster with 2 nodes. I have setup ACME top level option and the value of ca_url is set to the default let's encrypt url.
I have also configured a listener of port 5280, redirected from port 80 for the ACME challenge.

I have setup SRV records for my vhosts. I couldn't find any documentation regarding ACME in cluster mode.

1. Do both the nodes need to have the same certificates?
2. If I add a vhost and perform reload_config, will it request certificate for the new host or do I have to restart?
3. What is the correct way to setup SRV records for cluster mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have almost no experience with ACME, or ACME in ejabberd, so I'll give just some ideas that wou will have to check yourself:

> 1. Do both the nodes need to have the same certificates?

I'd say yes.

> 2. If I add a vhost and perform reload_config, will it request certificate for the new host or do I have to restart?

Looking at ejabberd_acme.erl, when reload_config is executed, register_certfiles() is executed as if ejabberd were started. So I'd say yes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If both the nodes require the same certificates, we can not really automate this using ejabberd_acme for cluster mode with the nodes running on different instance right? (Apart from sending the issued certificate from one machine to another)